# mysql.sock does not exist error in fresh install of MySQL on Arch Linux

Tags: mysql, mariadb, archlinux, mysql.sock

I'm trying to use `MySQL` on Arch Linux. it is already installed but this error comes up when I try to connect:

```
connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")'
```

I've looked for `/etc/my.cfg` but the file does not exist.
Something must have gone wrong during the installation.
How can I "purge" `MariaDB` and reinstall it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `archlinux` it is a vital idea to understand the package manager (`pacman`).  For the question about `/etc/my.cfg` you can run

```
pacman -Ql mariadb
```

there you will see that the file is actually called:

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

---

Arch linux will **not** configure the package for you, that is part of the **arch philosophy**.  It will provide example configurations, and even provide you with a `systemd` unit file

```
usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service
```

but it is your responsibility to ensure that the configuration is correct and actually start the daemon.

```
systemctl enable mysqld   # add the unit file to the boot sequence
systemctl start mysqld    # runs ExecStart= in the unit file
systemctl stop mysqld     # kills the daemon
systemctl disable mysqld  # remove unit from boot sequence
```

---

## reinstall

Since the word reinstall is in the title of the question and someone might find this question thanks to that: To reinstall `mariadb` you simply do

```
pacman -S mariadb
```

`pacman` will reinstall a package that is already installed, there is no need to remove the package (for completeness, package removal happens with `pacman -R`)

Comment: I know the basics commands of pacman, to install and remove. I tried to reinstall mariadb but the error is the same. The my.cfg file is in place. when i type systemctl status mysql i get "Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)"

Comment: @tino - you did not rename `my.cnf` to `my.cfg`, did you?

Answer (score 2):

as of 7-28-17 I had to do this on a new install. Newbie here might save someone some time. It was a real pain.

OK HERE IS THE DEAL!!!!!
INSTALL APACHE _ NO PROB

INSTALL MYSQL _PROBLEM
pacman -S mysql then before starting service

1. MUST UNCOMMENT INNODB IN:

   nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
2. then must initialize datadirectory before starting service:

   mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql

You need to initialize the MariaDB data directory prior to starting
   the service. This can be done with mysql_install_db command, e.g.:
   mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
Optional dependencies for mariadb
    galera: for MariaDB cluster with Galera WSREP
    perl-dbd-mysql: for mysqlhotcopy, mysql_convert_table_format and
    mysql_setpermission

Answer (score 1):

CNF file is `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` in Arch Linux.

One simple way I can reproduce your issue is when MariaDB is shut down. Sorry if it sounds dumb but as you did not mention it: is MariaDB started? `sudo systemctl start mysqld.service`

You should have a look at MariaDB logs to get some clue: `journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=mysqld.service` (maybe paste some part if you still don't get what is going on).

Answer (score 1):

This happens the first time you install MySQL and MariaDB. As [grochmal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6327365/grochmal) pointed out, you have to set up configurations before first use. But, the user teckk sent these three links in the [archlinux newbie corner](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1962943#p1962943):

1. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MariaDB
2. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MariaDB#Reset_the_root_password
3. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=51981

In short, you have to run the command below before starting the service:

```sh
sudo mariadb-install-db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

Optionally (recommended) you should [improve the initial security](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MariaDB#Improve_initial_security) by calling:

```sh
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Now you can start the service:

```sh
sudo systemctl start mariadb
```

Optionally, you could install and use a [graphical front-end tool](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MySQL#Graphical_tools).
Carry on with setting up the configurations as described in the [archwiki post on MariaDB Configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MariaDB#Configuration).